# How can you position a node relatively to another in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I would like to place a node 'B' 60 degrees of an arbitrary node 'A' between which there is a distance of 2cm. I can do this if node 'A' is at (0, 0), so 'B' would just be (60 : 2) from 'A', but what happens when 'A' is not at (0, 0)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. Some of them need the `calc` or `positioning` TikZ libraries (`\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}`).

The simplest way would be (using `calc` TikZ-library):

```
\node (A) at (2,4) {<content>};
\node (B) at ($ (A) + (60:2) $) {<content>};
```

You can also use the coordinate options `([<options>]<coordinate>)` to add a `shift` option, which doesn't require any libraries but looks a little funny.

```
\node (B) at ([shift={(60:2)}]A) {<content>};
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, what is the way that doesn't involve using other libraries?

Comment: @Skyork: I added this now.

Comment: Personally, I find `\draw (2,4) node(A){<content>} + (60:2) node(B){<content>};` easier.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen That's the most aesthetic option so far; you should write a real answer for it.

Comment: @RyanReich `\path` is more correct than `\draw` . There is nothing to draw in this case.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: That comment is for Marc, not me.

Comment: @RyanReich I would like to say that it's really aesthetic with `\path` :) but it's a good idea from Marc !

Comment: @AlainMatthes Thanks. I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 4):

Other methods with tikz and without library :

I prefer to use `\path` instead of `\draw`  Marc's  suggestion in the comment. We don't to draw anything in the path.

The second method is like one possibility given by Martin `\node (B) at ([shift={(60:2)}]A) {<content>};`. I propose `([shift={(A)}] 60:2)` If it's necessary to place others nodes relatively to A. It's preferable. We can add another possibility if we place other points it's to use a scope environment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (2,4) node(A){content A} + (60:2) node(B){content B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) at (2,4) {content A};
\node(B) at ([shift={(A)}] 60:2) {content B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (2,4) {content A};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(A)}]
      \node (B) at ( 60:2) {content B};
      \node (C) at ( -60:3) {content C};
 \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only 2 methods?

Comment: 2 for me ( you forgot Martin's answer ). I think it's not useful to add complexity. It's a question about Tikz and  it' s not very interesting to know that you can use `\pstVerb{/xyxyadd {3 2 roll add 3 1 roll add exch} bind def}%`.

Answer (score 0):

With PSTricks, I know there are 6 methods as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{unit=0.5cm,saveNodeCoors}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \pscircle(A){2}
    \pnode[2;60](A){B}
    \psdots(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \pscircle(A){2}
    \pnode([nodesep=2,angle=60]A){B}
    \psdots(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \pscircle(A){2}
    \rput(A){\pnode(2;60){B}}
    \psdots(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \pscircle(A){2}
    \nodexn{(A)+(2;60)}{B}
    \psdots(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \pscircle(A){2}
    \pstVerb{/xyxyadd {3 2 roll add 3 1 roll add exch} bind def}%
    \pnode(!2 60 PtoC N-A.x N-A.y xyxyadd){B}
    \psdots(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \pscircle(A){2}
    \pstVerb{/xyxyadd {3 2 roll add 3 1 roll add exch} bind def}%
    \curvepnode{60}{2 t PtoC N-A.x N-A.y xyxyadd}{B}
    \psdots(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Explanation:

Let we have a node `A` at `(2,2)`. For the sake of readability, I draw a circle of radius 2 with `A` as its center.

- Method 1: `\pnode[2;60](A){B}`
- Method 2: `\pnode([nodesep=2,angle=60]A){B}`
- Method 3: `\rput(A){\pnode(2;60){B}}`
- Method 4: `\nodexn{(A)+(2;60)}{B}`
- Method 5:

  ```
  \pstVerb{/xyxyadd {3 2 roll add 3 1 roll add exch} bind def}%
  \pnode(!2 60 PtoC N-A.x N-A.y xyxyadd){B}
  ```
- Method 6:

  ```
  \pstVerb{/xyxyadd {3 2 roll add 3 1 roll add exch} bind def}%
  \curvepnode{60}{2 t PtoC N-A.x N-A.y xyxyadd}{B}
  ```