# How to use each of the following operators defined in pst-tools?

Tags: pstricks

I cannot find any documentation explaining how to use each of the following operators defined in `pst-tools`.

[image]

Could you give practical examples (such as simplifying vector addition

```
\pnode(2,2){A}
\pscircle(A){2}
\pstVerb{/xyxyadd {3 2 roll add 3 1 roll add exch} bind def}%
\pnode(!2 60 PtoC N-A.x N-A.y xyxyadd){B}
```

that is equal to `\nodexn{(A)+(2;60)}{B}` where `\pnode(2,2){A}`) for each operator? I believe that the given answer will be useful for most of us.

### Edit:

The real scenario is to apply complex number addition to simplify method 5 and method 6 in [the following answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108839/19356).

Comment: Time for a user name change already `Karl's students`? :)

Comment: They are standard mathematical functions so it isn't really clear what kind of example you would want, If you want to plot factorial then /factorial will be useful, otherwise less so... the cx ones are just the arithmetic operations on complex numbers encoded as a pair of reals.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: For example, how to use `cxadd` if I want to add  a point `(2,2)` and another point `(2;60)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example of `cxadd` (addition of complex numbers) Just using gs on the commandline.

```
$ gs
GPL Ghostscript 9.04 (2011-08-05)
Copyright (C) 2011 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
GS>(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro)run
GS>[2 2] [2 60] cxadd ==
[4 62]
GS>
```

Comment: that is already shown in the above list ... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert yes I know which is why I originally just gave a comment but OP particularly asked for this example so...