# Position two touching nodes at a certain angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I have found multiple explanations of how to position two nodes at a certain angel, such as [How can you position a node relatively to another in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23536).

My question now is:

> How can position the second node relative to the first such that both
>   touch without knowing their sizes a priori?

As this is inside a macro, I really do not know the size of the nodes a priori. Following the example in the above link, I would like

```
\node (A) at (2,4) {<content1>};
\node (B) at ($ (A) + (60:???) $) {<content2>};
```

to make the two nodes A and B touch at a 60° angle without knowing what content1 and content2 is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Position `B` at `A.60`, and set `anchor=240`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle,draw,outer sep=0pt] (A) {foo bar baz};
\node [circle,draw,anchor=240,outer sep=0pt] (B) at (A.60)  {foobaz};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ChristianStump No, 240 = 60 + 180. You The anchor of the `B` node, should be on the opposite side of the circle compared to the position on the `A` node.